# Can I signup with Facebook with custom domain email?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use my site mail to signup with Facebook, like `myname@example.com`, but Facebook is reporting it as invalid mail. So, are we not allowed to use anything other than Gmail, Yahoo etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible, however it could be that your email domain is flagged somehow as unreliable. This doesn't *per se* mean that it flagged yours specifically but the algorithm they use nonetheless did so anyway.

It could also be the following: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=3956397517776

They asked the same question here and the problem is maybe that emails containing words like info or mail like info@example.com are not personal enough.

Comment: So, there is no way to signup with my custom domain mail

Comment: Sorry I phrased it wrong, it should be possible..

Comment: So is there any way to identify that Facebook flagged my domain as unreliable or I need to signup with just reliable domains like gmail/yahoo

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for you to sign up with custom domain email. This isn't an issue. However, try signing up with a regular email (Gmail, Yahoo or Microsoft) and change your email to your desired email. Maybe this could work.

Comment: If Facebook reporting an email invalid, after chaging it user would not be able to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the e-mail service provider that you use with your custom domain, you may be able to use a **"+"** sign to make your e-mail address valid for Facebook.

G Suite for example ignores the **"+"** sign and everything afterwards in e-mail addresses. If your e-mail address is `contact@customdomain.com` and you are using G Suite, you can sign up to Facebook with **`contact+facebook@customdomain.com`**.

Any e-mail sent to `contact+facebook@customdomain.com` will end up in the inbox of `contact@customdomain.com` because G Suite ignores everything after the **"+"**.